# How does the indexOf() method works with array as a search value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexof

When I put only one letter words ("s", "z" and so on) in that array it works, but in this case it doesn't and I don't know why. I know it is something in that condition, because when I use only "document.querySelector(".area1").textContent = result;" without the if statement it works...

[image: My js code]

Comment: please add the code in **text form** to the question. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: What 's exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sivaprasad I want to put some text, for example "Mně mě Mě mně" then I'm gonna push button "replace" and I want this output "M__ m__ M__ m__" with input like this "s z S Z" it works, but with that case above doesn't...

Comment: What do you mean by indexOf(...lett). I don't know what the three dots '...' in it refers to (gud if someone can explain it). To my knowledge it should accept a string. That might be the problem with your condition as you are doubting. Also it is advisable not to use replace() in such a way.

Comment: I know that it's a bit weird code, but I'm wondering why in the case where var lett = ["s", "S", "z", "Z"] function nahradaTwo() works, but in the case above doesn't and my question is WHY, where is the difference between these 2 arrays?

Comment: @PetrVomáčka did it work for words without "s"?

Comment: Why would you expect the spread syntax `...` to work with the `indexOf` function? That is not how `indexOf` works.

Comment: @JSDEV the spread syntax allows you to use an array instead of separate parameters to a function. if an array `a` contains `[1,3,5,7]` then `f(...a)` is the same as `f(1,3,5,7)`. That is all.

Comment: So the only way `...` could work here with the `indexOf` function is if the array `lett` contained valid parameters to `indexOf`, e.g. `['Mě', 33]` to search for 'Mě' starting from the 33th char.

Comment: @JSDEV But can you tell me why it is not advisable to use replace in this way? Would it be preferable to search for `[Mm]` and use a backreference for the replacement, or what?

Comment: But it doesn’t work without that three dots, it takes only the first item of that array then, it is like var nums = [1,2,3,4], Math.max(nums), it also doesnt work, u need to change it like this Math.max(...nums)

Comment: @barbsan Yea, with one letter words it works.

Comment: @PetrVomáčka rly? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wYbGEp?editors=0011

Comment: @MrLister using replace() as many times as we need a replacement would be a bad way of hardcoding. Should use looping instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below code works for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <button id="replaceBtn">Replace</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lett = ["Mně", "mě", "Mě", "mně"],//whatever you want to replace
    replaceLett = ["M__","m_","M_","m__"],//whatever you want to replace with
    texts = "Mně mě Mě mně",//your string
    replaceButton = document.getElementById("replaceBtn"),
    reg = [];

    lett.forEach(function(item){
      reg.push(new RegExp(item,"g"));//forming a regular expression for global replacement
    });   
    console.log(reg);
    replaceButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      lett.forEach(function(item, index){
        texts = texts.replace(reg[index], replaceLett[index]);
        console.log(texts);
      });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

[image]